# Unable to deploy/debug a Windows 10 Iot Core app on Raspberry PI 2

Tags: windowsiot

When I try to deploy from a developer machine that is on another domain the deployment fails.

Visual Studio gives me this Message:
*The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging.*

Works fine when I deploy from a machine that is not in a domain.
I've been searching the web for days now but I'm not able to find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have Windows 10 IoT-Core Build 10586 on your Pi, but you don't have Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 installed. You need to use the new Universal (Unencrypted Mode) authentication method with build 10586. You can read more about this issue here: http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/721/Win-10-IoT-Core-Visual-Studio-2015-Update-1-App-Deployment-and-Debug-Requirements

Comment: Thank you.  I was missing the Update 1 on my developer machine.  My Laptop outside the domain is running the Community editiion With Update 1 and my Developer machine was running Professional without Update 1.